# Publish HTML Javadoc with Gradle

Tags: gradle

We are publishing Javadoc as a jar through a Maven publish task, but I would like to know now if there is an easy way to upload the HTML directory of the Javadoc (and maybe other pages like Swagger documentation) to a raw Nexus repository?

I've seen I can call curl and scp through Groovy, but I'd rather use a Gradle task if it's possible. I've tried with an Upload task but did not succeed to add a whole directory as artefact in a configuration. I have also looked at dashboards but it is not included.